# Second monitor not being detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop; When I was using Windows 10 the monitor was being detected and working fine, however, it doesn't seem to be working in Ubuntu.  It does not seem to be detected in settings, however, in Nvidia server settings it is being recognised.  I have tried a couple different things in an attempt to fix it, including reinstalling nvidia drivers, using sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt update, installing some bluetooth drivers, but nothing seems to be working and the monitor is just displaying a no signal message.  My laptop has an integrated AMD graphics chip as well as a dedicated Nvidia gtx 1650ti.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does installing Bluetooth drivers have to do with the monitor?

Comment: @David A youtube tutorial about the issue said installing bluetooth drivers fixed it for them